# C# copy image form PowerPoint to Word

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, powerpoint, file-transfer

I need a application to copy text and images form PowerPoint to Word. I use this libraries: Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

The text s easy to transfer, but when I find in PowerPoint a shape containing only a image, it show this error: "**A generic error occured GDI+**", at this part of code:

```
foreach (PowerPoint.Shape shape in slide.Shapes)
{
   if (shape.HasTextFrame != MsoTriState.msoTrue){
      shape.Copy();
      Image img = (Image)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
      string filepath = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop + "\\img.jpg";
      if (File.Exists(filepath))
      {
         File.Delete(filepath);
      }
      img.Save(filepath);
      doc.Shapes.AddPicture(filepath, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
   }
}
```

How can I copy a shape containing a image from PowerPoint to Word in this cirumstances?
Any help is welcome. I prefer some code sample.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it shape.Copy() or Clipboard.GetData(..) which fails?

Comment: Fails at Clipboard.GetData(..)

Comment: The code works fine on my Win7 box (.Net4 and Office 2010). Which OS it is running under and which version of .Net?

Comment: I have .Net 3.5 and Office 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rewrite your code like this, will it work? GetImage will do an automatic conversion to make sure it's an image. If you know it's a bitmap you could include the check I have in the code to ensure the clipboard actually contains an image.

```
shape.Copy();
bool imgOk = Clipboard.ContainsImage();
if (imgOk)
{
    Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
    MessageBox.Show(imgOk.ToString());
    string filepath = @"c:\temp\img.jpg";
    if (File.Exists(filepath))
    {
        File.Delete(filepath);
    }
    img.Save(filepath);
}
```