# save a file in memory instead of a physical path

Tags: c#, export, interop, powerpoint, slide

I am trying to use Office Interop assembly to export a PowerPoint slide to an image. The `SaveAs()`, `SaveCopyAs()`, and `Export()` methods all accept a physical path as the output folder.

I want to put it in memory for further processing instead of creating a bunch of images on disks that I have to clear them later.

How can I export a slide and hold it in the memory temporarily instead of saving it in a physical folder?

Comment: Copy it to the clipboard and then paste it to where you want it: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358182/c-sharp-copy-image-form-powerpoint-to-word>  for the copy and then this for the paste and save <http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/05/save-picture-from-clipboard-to-file-using-c/>

Answer (score 1):

Calling the Slide's .Copy method will put the slide on the clipboard in a number of formats, including PNG, GIF, JPG, DIB, BMP and metafile/enhanced metafile.

It should be possible to access the format you want from there.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Couldn't find much information online, some codes would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid I've no idea how you'd do it in C#, but to get the slide on the clipboard in various formats, you'd simply call the .Copy method on the Slide object you're after.

Comment: I finally have to give up using office interop. We can't install office on our server, but thanks for your replies. I am currently researching the Open XML SDK and hopefully there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of writing an Office Apps files straight to memory. You can look at Open XML SDK for Office, but i think, it will be easier if you just save the image to a file and load it through memorystream.